# C - Output is rounded

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int Sum=0,numbers;
  double Average;
  int counter = 0;

   printf("\nPlease Enter the Numbers one by one\n");
   for(;;) {
     scanf("%d",&numbers);
     if(numbers == 0) {
        break;
     }
     else {
       Sum = Sum + numbers;
       counter++;
     }
   }

   Average = Sum/counter;

   printf("\nSum of the %d Numbers = %d",counter, Sum);
   printf("\nAverage of the %d Numbers = %.4f",counter, Average);

  return 0;
}
```

I wrote a program which is able to take endless numbers of input add them into one variable and output the average of all the input numbers when the key 0 is pressed.

However, the problem is that when I type in for example 5 and 2 the sum variable has a value of 7. And counter has a value of 2.

However when the mathematical operation starts `Average = SUM/Counter`, the
result is 3.00 not 3.500....

Anyone knows where my problem is?

Would appreciate any help.

Cheers

Marco

Comment: because SUM is int... Typecast the result to double

Comment: Thank you very much its working =).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Average = Sum/counter;
```

Sum is int.

```
Average = (double)Sum/counter;
```

should do it. You need to typecast one of the operands to get the desired result, floating point in this case.

Comment: You need to cast the numerator or denominator before the division to get a double result.  Casting the result will result in an integer result. Note that this is what you did but not what you described.

Comment: Thats what I meant. The wording might be misleading. I will change it

Answer (score 3):

`Sum` and `counter` are both of type `int`, so integer division is performed and their result is also of type `int`.

You need to cast one of the operands to `double` so that it does floating point division:

```
Average = (double)Sum/counter;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to post comments. So I have to provide it as answer:

dbush's answer is more accurate:

You need to cast one of the **operands**, not the **result**.

Would you cast the result, it still were 3.00.